# Review of an answer for finding a limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {{n!} \over {(n + 1)(n + 2)...(2n)}} = {{n!} \over {{{(2n)!} \over {n!}}}} =   \cr 
  & {{n!n!} \over {2n!}} = {{n!} \over 2} =  + \infty  \cr} $$

The first equality can be explained by an example:

$$\eqalign{
  & n = 5  \cr 
  & {{5!} \over {6!...10!}} \cr} $$

Is it right? because something's telling me it isn't.

Comment: No $(2n)!\ne 2n!$

Comment: Consider the quantity $2n\choose n$

Comment: @abiessu, Can you direct me how to use it?

Comment: This is related to Catalan numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: Welcome to Warwick, you'll learn to love sequences, or you shall fall.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is not a good fit for this questions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info).

Answer (score 1):

$n!$ can be expressed as a polynomial of $n$:

$$n! = \prod_{i=0}^n (n-i) = n^{n+1} + \cdots$$

This shows that $n!$ is a $n+1$-degree polynomial of $n$. Then, the greatest power of $n$ that you can find in this polynomial is $n^{n+1}$.
The greatest power that you can obtain from $n!n!$ is $n^{n+1}n^{n+1} = n^{2n+2}$ with coefficient $1$. Also, the greatest power of the polynomial of $(2n)!$ is $(2n)^{2n+1}$ with coefficient 1.

The ratio between the maximum powers is :
$$\frac{n^{2n+2}}{(2n)^{2n+1}} = \frac{n^{2n+1}n}{2^{2n+1}n^{2n+1}} = \frac{n}{2^{2n+1}}$$

This ratio determinates the behavior of the limit when $n$ goes to infinity.
In particular:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n!n!}{(2n)!} = \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n}{2^{2n+1}} = 0$$